# How to evalute code in the chain or pretend callback function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

I dynamically add an image on my page :

```
<div class="simple_overlay" id="overlay">
   <img src="" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("a[rel]").overlay({
        var source = this.getTrigger().attr('href');
        this.getOverlay().find("img").attr({'src': source});
    });
});
</script>
```

Now, I need to get width of the new image and calculate `margin-left` corresponding to it. Native jQuery Tools methods doesn't work, because when overlay is loading, image hasn't yet loaded and container `#overlay` width is 0.
Is there any option to emulate callback on this chain, so i can use `width()` right after `attr()` has evaluated?

Comment: How about tying the behavior to the image, and make it work with its `$(this).parent()` on load?

Comment: @Evadne Wu: In that case image will "jump" while it margins change. It is bad for users.

Comment: Animate the change?  Make the image `display:none` or `visibility:hidden` until explicitly revealed by script?

Comment: A work-around would be to set the width of `#overlay` to a fixed value and the width of the image to 100%. This approach will save you the hassle of evaluating different widths while retaining a clean layout (which I'm guessing is what you try to achieve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the images [`load` event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) (not to be confused with `window.load`), like this:

```
$("a[rel]").overlay({
    var source = this.getTrigger().attr('href');
    this.getOverlay().find("img").one('load', function() {
      //run your code here, the image is loaded and is "this"
    }).each(function() {
      if (this.complete) $(this).load(); //trigger load, handles from cache cases
    }).attr({'src': source});
});
```

This uses [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to run your code only once.  The `load` event fires when *that* image is loaded...but this doesn't always fire when loading it from cache (depending on browser), which is what the [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is for.  If the browser loaded it from cache *and* fired the event...that's ok too, the [`.one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) handles that, code still runs once in every case :)